# Erro na decodificação no request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x

Estou enviando a segiunte string via post (JavaScript) para meu servidor bootle(Python):

```
query = {
'wiki': `Tr%E1%BA%A7n_H%C6%B0ng_%C4%90%E1%BA%A1o`,
'uid':'f17afd66aae3a'
}

$.post(url, query, function(data, status){}):
```

Porém quando vou imprimir o que recebo do post dá o seguinte resultado:

`b'uid=f17afd66aae3a&wiki=Tr%25E1%25BA%25A7n_H%25C6%25B0ng_%25C4%2590%25E1%25BA%25A1o'` - Primeiro print

No caso eu faço dois split transformando essa string binária em um dicionário atraves da função `translate(postdata)`.

`{'uid': 'f17afd66aae3a', 'wiki': 'Tr%25E1%25BA%25A7n_H%25C6%25B0ng_%25C4%2590%25E1%25BA%25A1o'}` - Segundo print

E como meu codigo irá acessar o artigo do wikipedia com tal nome:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%E1%BA%A7n_H%C6%B0ng_%C4%90%E1%BA%A1o`

Não consgigo acessalo pois meu request fica com a sequinte url:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%25E1%25BA%25A7n_H%25C6%25B0ng_%25C4%2590%25E1%25BA%25A1o`

Que gera um erro por não existir a pagina.

Está aí meu codigo no bottle:

```
@post('/update_article')                                                        
@enable_cors                                                                    
def update_article_post():                                       
    token = request.cookies.get('token', '0')                                   
    if load_token(token):                                                       
        postdata = request.body.read()
        print(postdata)                                        
        dici = translate(postdata)                                              
        print(dici)                                                             
       # res = update_article(dici['uid'], dici['wiki'])                        
       # return {'data': res}                                                   
    else:                                                                       
         return redirect('/login.html')
```

Existe alguma forma de receber o post da forma certa, ou codificar essa string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#html-form-handling) é possível acessar os parâmetros recebidos de um POST usando `request.forms.get('campo')`.

Então tua pergunta parece que pode ser resolvido com o código:

```py
wiki = request.forms.get('wiki')
```

Caso o Bottle não faça o decode automático da string tu pode usar o método [`urlli.parse.unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote).

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote

print(unquote('Tr%25E1%25BA%25A7n_H%25C6%25B0ng_%25C4%2590%25E1%25BA%25A1o'))
# Saída: Trần_Hưng_Đạo
```

Answer (score 1):

tente codificar com base64

dai no servidor Python tente decodificar a string antes de jogar na wiki, use o b64decode do Python

```
import base64
Request = 'cmVzcG9zdGEgZGVjb2RpZmljYWRhIA==' 
resposta = base64.b64decode(Request)
print(resposta)
```

a saida sera

```
resposta decodificada
```